# What algebraic structure is the set of natural numbers and addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What algebraic structure is the set of natural numbers and addition?

I understand that

$$\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$$

and $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are rings and $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are fields with normal addition and multiplication operations (right?)

So what algebraic structure is $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: [Monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid)

Comment: @Calvin: without $0$ you only get a semigroup (since $0$ is the additive identity).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My assumption was that the natural numbers included 0. I don't particularly like the phrase natural numbers due to the ambiguity involved. I prefer to say positive integers / non-negative integers.

Comment: Wikipedia adopts the Bourbaki definition of a ring that includes a multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The natural numbers assuming $0$ is included are a monoid under multiplication and also a monoid under addition. Under both addition and multiplication $\mathbb N$ is whats called a semiring.

Edit: I might add that $\mathbb N$ under multiplication is actually rather interesting. In particular $(\mathbb N,\cdot)$ is the free abelian monoid on countably many generators.

Comment: What if 0 is excluded?

Comment: Then you don't get a semiring because you don't have a zero, you also don't have a monoid under addition, it's what's called a semigroup now. But you still have a monoid under multiplication.

Comment: The natural numbers (excluding $0$) under addition would be a semigroup (set with an associative operation, but no inverses and no identity). Under multiplciation, it would still be a monoid (even without $0$, since the identity element under multiplication is $1$).

Comment: Could someone recommend a listing of abstract algebraic structures with its features and examples?  I have the feeling someone must have tabulated that.

Comment: @Problemania There's this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures).

Comment: Would it be more specific and still correct to say that the natural numbers are a commutative/abelian monoid under addition and under multiplication?